# Powershell replace a string like "-anything_" with "_"

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

I am trying to replace a string in my file names. The string always begins with a "-" and ends with a "_". The middle could be numbers, text or both.

I have had success changing "-" to "", but the regex is killing me. I am a complete beginner, so this whole code is cobbled together from other articles.

```
$baseDirectory = "C:\Test\Rename\"
$a = "\-(.*?)\_"
$b = "_"

$Include = '*.jpg'

Pushd $baseDirectory

Get-ChildItem -Filter "*$a*" -Recurse|
  Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace $a,$b} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

PopD
```

**Goal**
A121000-22_01.jpg --> A121000_01.jpg
A478BFE-876_02.jpg --> A478BFE_02.jpg
A124568-59B_03.jpg --> A124568_03.jpg

The result is no change.

Comment: Your replace code works for me if I remove the backslash characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your existing regex is very close. There's no need to replace with `_`.

#### Option 1

You can change the lazy quantifier `(.*?)` to a character exception class `[^_]*` as can be seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/E6A9na/1).

```
-[^_]*
```

This matches:

- `-` this character literally.
- `[^_]*` any character except `_` any number of times (this stops once it reaches `_`).

---

#### Option 2

If you need to ensure the `_` character exists, then you can use the following instead as seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/E6A9na/2) (notice the last line doesn't get matched).

```
-[^_]*(?=_)
```

This matches:

- `-` this character literally.
- `[^_]*` any character except `_` any number of times (this stops once it reaches `_`).
- `(?=_)` ensures the following character is `_` literally

---

### Additionally

I changed your code to the following and it worked for me (replaced `-Filter "*$a*"` with `-Include "*.jpg"`):

```
$baseDirectory = "C:\test\Rename"
$a = "-[^_]*(?=_)"

Pushd $baseDirectory

Get-ChildItem -Include "*.jpg" -Recurse|
  Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace $a,""} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

PopD
```